# Use competitive nets to prevent overfitting

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I'm learning about neural nets at the moment.
Now I asked myself if it is possible to use a preceding competitive net to prevent overfitting, because competitive nets are said to reduce correlation between data.

What I exactly mean is:

1. Input into competitive net
2. Output from competitive net into the actual neural neural net

I couldn't find any ressource about that so I'm asking here.
Would be happy if you can provide me a link or anything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any work that specifically uses a separate competitive network, but I did find some work that incorporates competitive layers that directly integrate into a neural net model: [link](http://jsalatas.ictpro.gr/implementation-of-competitive-learning-networks-for-weka/).

You may also want to research dropout if you haven't already.  Dropout is a very powerful technique to address the problem of overfitting, and it actually has some loose connection to what you're describing: in a sense, dropout provides a way for an exponential number of thinned networks to "compete" to prevent co-adaption.